# Hypernym for Urban/Suburban

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that can describe the differentiation between urban and suburban localities.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developed_environments) lists them as "different types of developed settlements" so I thought about calling it *settlement type* but I'm hoping there might be something more straightforward and accessible.

If possible, a single word would be ideal. Otherwise, two words is fine, as long as they're not too long.  It's going to be part of a title for a PowerPoint slide.

Comment: Density is what differentiates the two.

Comment: Locale? District? Region? ("Type of" etc).

Comment: @YosefBaskin I think *population density* might be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @AffableAmbler do be aware though that not all heavily built up urban areas have high populations. Think about a city's central business district, lots of buildings and lots of people in the day, but not at night. That would have a pretty low population density if you are talking about residential rather than transitory population. I'd probably talk about 'urban form' http://www.rtpi.org.uk/media/1360966/urban%20form%20and%20sustainability%20briefing.pdf

Comment: The key difference really concerns ***outskirts / city centre***. I doubt there's anything like an established "hypernym" for the concept, but ***centrality*** might work as a nonce coinage.

Comment: City centre ... more urban ... suburban ... rural/isolated are the headings I use for settlements in a folder I've made. Note that (a) 'population density' isn't really a serious contender for a synonym (of regions) here; (b) population density is possibly _lower_ in many city centres than in the corresponding outskirts.

Comment: Also, zones in the Urban to Rural Urban Transect   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transect_(urban)

Comment: Urban areas with surrounding suburbs are usually much more heavily populated than rural areas.  The U.S. Census calls them Standard Metropolitan Statistical Areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the term 'zoning', since the type and application of building in each zone depends on the zoning regulations. An urban area would include living areas, such as apartments, but it would not include residential areas, defined by single-family houses. A suburban area would not have buildings over a certain height, and would have few or no buildings for professional offices. It seems a bit clumsy, since I don't think you can use 'zone', only 'zoning'.

Comment: That is exactly what we ended up going with.  I'm glad to get a concurring opinion.